# How to use file links in included PHP file

Tags: php, web

index.php:

```php
<?php require_once("include/header.php") ?>
```

header.php:

```php
<?php require_once("../../include/config.php") ?>
```

I have php files and I need to access them using the included file so I need to use something like  `<?php require_once("../../include/config.php") ?>` that will work with relative paths to this header.php, not to the file which includes my header.

Comment: To answer this question, we would need more information about the structure of your files and folders. `../` means that you go up one folder in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `include` / `require` / `require_once` statements using relative files are relative to the PHP process' current working directory which depends on how PHP runs. You can get the current working directory using the [`getcwd()`](https://php.net/getcwd) function and change it at runtime using [`chdir()`](https://php.net/chdir).

If you want to include a file relative to the current file regardless of the current directory, you can do something like:

```
<?php require_once(realpath(__DIR__) . "/../../include/config.php") ?>
```

Note the use of `__DIR__` which is a magic constant that always represents the directory of file it is written in (not the including file).

Answer (score 0):

Try this
   `<?php require_once("./include/header.php") ?>`

Comment: It works for header.php, but not for requiring config.php